# What is “Dune” as referred to by the Baron

Tags: dialogue, dune-2021

Why does Baron use the word “Dune” in *Dune* (2021) movie when referring to controlling Arrakis.

> My desert. My Arrakis. My Dune.

I’m assuming *Dune* is more than a reference to sand dunes.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious. I had a hard time googling this as the words the movie name itself

Comment: It *is* a bit obvious, as "Dune" is pretty much the nickname of planet Arrakis. But I give you that it might not be immediately clear from the film, especially if you don't know the other films/books.

Comment: Oh right I didn’t realise it’s a nickname for the planet!

Comment: Just checked, yeah it's not explained in the film at all. I avoided using the wiki in case I spoilt something outside the 2021 film

Comment: You're reading way too much into it. He's referring to the planet Arrakis, aka Dune.

Comment: Villeneuve is really leaning hard into the show-don't-tell style of storytelling. There's very few direct exposition in the movie but the Dune universe has a ton of concepts that needs to be introduced to audiences. For example instead of explaining what the Voice is or how it works he shows Paul being taught how to use the Voice by his mother. The Baron saying "My Arrakis! My Dune!" is his subtle way **of explaining** that Dune is another name for Arrakis. This style of storytelling is subtle and is sometimes open to interpretation but it works in avoiding awkward monologues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the nickname of the planet Arrakis

> Arrakis, also known as "Dune"

- from [dune.fandom.com](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Arrakis)

Full credit to [@NapoleanWilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson) for the answer in comments!